# Какой функционал строк кода

Tags: python

```
import time
start = time.time()                 
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as f: 
 data = f.read().split()         
 s = ''
 for i in data:
     if int(i) % 2 == 0:         
         if len(set(list(i))) == len(i):                             #какой
             s += i                                                        #функционал этих
         else:                                                              #4 строк
             s += ''.join(sorted(set(list(i)), key=i.index)) #кода
         s += ' '                
 finish = time.time()
 result = finish - start        
 print(s, "Program time: " + str(result) + " seconds.")
```

Comment: `len(set(list(i))) == len(i)` — проверяет, что в `i` нет повторяющихся цифр (при этом `list` здесь совершенно бессмысленный)

Answer (score 1):

```
if int(i) % 2 == 0:  # если число четное

if len(set(list(i))) == len(i): # если количество неповторяющихся цифр в числе == количество цифр в числе

s += i # конкатенация строки и рассматриваемого числа

s += ''.join(sorted(set(list(i)), key=i.index)) # убираем повторяющие цифры из числа, например: 771225 ---> 7125 и конкатенируем строку с рассматриваемым числом
```